# Windows Service Event Firing but not updating DB (code works in win form)

Tags: c#, database

I've got a windows service program with a timer, the elapsed event fires from my default test but it doesnt update the DB. The Same exact code works in a windows form button click event. Heres the Code. Using a 3 tier architecture and sql server 2012.

```
namespace DALStations
{
class GetUpdate
{
    DALConnection connectstring;

    public GetUpdate()
    {
        connectstring = new DALConnection();
    }

             public void  UpdateCommands() //SqlCommand
            {

                SqlCommand authorize = new SqlCommand();

                 authorize.CommandText = "dbo.UpdateTest";
                authorize.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                authorize.Connection = connectstring.GetConnection();


                 authorize.Connection.Open();                    
                authorize.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 authorize.Connection.Close();

            }

}
}
```

**BAL**

```
namespace BALStations
{
class BAL
{

    //public void UpdateTest()
    //{
    //    new DALTest().Updatetest();
    //}


    public void CallUpdateProcedure()
    {

        new GetUpdate().UpdateCommands();
    }
  }
}

 Service Layer or UI

namespace Stations
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;


      public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Process();

    }

    public void Process()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);

        // Set the Interval to 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 3000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Summit Works\Authorized Timer\Details.txt", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Service Start {0}", DateTime.Now, true);
        }
        aTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender,
 System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {         

       BAL bal = new BAL();
       bal.CallUpdateProcedure(); 

    }     


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to permissions.

What identity is the windows service running as, and does it have execute permission on the stored procedure?

Goto Services and check your service's identity. It's probably running as `NETWORK SERVICE` or `LOCAL SYSTEM`

```
USE MYDatabase
GO

CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS;
GO

CREATE USER [NETWORK SERVICE] FOR LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = YourDatabase;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.UpdateTest TO  [NETWORK SERVICE];
```

You could give 'more' permissions with by adding to dbo role (but I wouldn't go down this route):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbo', 'NETWORK SERVICE'
```

Comment: I have a dummy windows form app that is using the same code for a button click event which works, basically copy and pasted service code to form app and it works

Comment: Yes, and when you run from windows form it runs as you, who presumably has the necessary permissions. I do actually know what I'm talking about!

Comment: how can i check the windows service identity, I haven't done anything special to give it exec permission. I'll google how to do that

Comment: autolog properties for the service is set to true

Comment: that statement makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Ok, how can I grant execute permissions

Comment: how can i check my databases network service?

Comment: CREATE LOGIN [YOURCOMPUTERNAME\NETWORK SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS;
GO.........NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: i would if i could but ill mark as answer for those points